# Plot different variables in the same graph for different years

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, graph, correlation

I have a df like this

```
date           year    month    day    forecast    value    error
2018-01-01     2018    01       01     14000       13902    98
2018-01-02     2018    01       02     13290       13200    90
2018-01-03     2018    01       03     12030       12040    -10
2018-01-04     2018    01       04     13239       13239    0
2018-01-05     2018    01       05     13100       13290    -190
.
.
.
.
.
2019-01-01     2019    01       01     13247       13200    47
2019-01-02     2019    01       02     13248       13200    48
2019-01-03     2019    01       03     13240       13200    40
2019-01-04     2019    01       04     13239       13200    39
2019-01-05     2019    01       05     13100       13200    -100
.
.
.
.
.
2020-01-01     2020    01       01     14000       13902    98
2020-01-02     2020    01       02     13290       13200    90
2020-01-03     2020    01       03     12030       12040    -10
2020-01-04     2020    01       04     13239       13239    0
2020-01-05     2020    01       05     13100       13290    -190
.
.
.
```

And I want to plot the column error but for different years in the same plot. I want to put in the same plot different lines, one for the error in 2018, other for the error in 2019 and another for the error in 2020, but I do not know how to do it.

I tried using this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = error, colour = year)) + geom_line()
```

but it shows this graph, were lines are not connected and I do not know how to make them connect all in one line for each year. (The graph is in spanish but please in the answer use the name I used in english so more people can understand my doubt, thanks!!!)

[image]

Comment: Try adding the grouping term: `ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = error, colour = factor(year), group=year)) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = error, color = factor(year))) + geom_line()
```

Comment: i need them to be fro january to december and with that it makes 3 different lines with 3 different colours but not one above from the other, they are all in the same line one continued by the other @RonakShah